# Why some command being skipped in Linux shell?

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash 
while [ 1 ] 
do
read  -s -n 1  key
echo -n $key && echo -n $key >> log
done
```

I save this shell as run.sh and run it  using "./run.sh"
If I input characters very quickly , the string on the console
sometimes is different from the string in the log file.

```
./run.sh
dhassudhasfuadhasfuash
ctrl+c
cat log
dhasudhasfuadhasfuash
```

How to explain this?

Comment: `-n 1` causes the line to be read unbuffered. I guess that if you don't write each character separately to the log file, but instead collect them in a variable and if you are done entering, write them in a log file, you won't have missing characters anymore, or maybe only VERY infrequently.

Comment: you can try it on your pc to check this strange thing

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Odd, but sounds like you are you coming up against a race condition where you've written to stdin before the loop as had a chance to get back round to the read command.

How about trying the script without the silent option, so you can see at which point characters are being read...

```
read -p " reading:" -n 1 key
```

to which I'm sure you'd get something like
 reading:dd reading:hh reading:aa reading: sss reading:....